# In mongoDB $collection->find() doesn't works

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is a code i'm trying to making work, i'll use it for an authentification page on my website:

```
<?php

 $m = new MongoClient();

 $db = $m->myDB;

 $collection = $db->users;

 $cursor = $collection->find({"Login":"admin","Password":"password"});

 echo "No Error";

?>
```

I already created and filled the collection "users", and i get a result when i put this in the terminal:

```
db.users.find({"Login":"admin","Password":"password"})
```

But i doesn't work in the script, i.e the page doesn't echo "No Error"

Thanks

p.s:

I inserted data this way in my collection:

```
$m = new MongoClient();

$db = $m->myDB;

$collection = $db->users;

$document = array( 
  "Login" => "admin", 
  "Password" => "password"
);
$collection->insert($document);
```

Comment: I encourage you to turn on error reporting, `$collection->find({"Login":"admin","Password":"password"});` is not valid PHP code.

Comment: @malarzm i was inspired by this link to make my code: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm                                   For me it should work that's why i post a comment here

Comment: can you show us how you inserted data to your collection?

Comment: it should be in `key=>value` pair.

Comment: @KhairulIslam i just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// MongoClient
$m = new MongoClient();

// Select your database
$db = $m->selectDB('database_name');

// MongoCollection, pasing $db and collection name
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');

// Your query
$query = array(
    'Login' => 'admin',
    'Password' => 'password'
);

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
var_dump($cursor);
```

You can find more at http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Comment: Thanks, but how do i display the document return by find() on my page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your data from collection in this way also-

```
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully" . "<br/>";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected" . "<br/>";

   // select a collection
   $collection =  $db->users;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully" . "<br/>";

   // find all informations
   $cursor = $collection->find();

   // iterate cursor to display Login
   foreach ($cursor as $info) {
      echo $info["Login"] . "\n";
   }
```